# The geometrical meaning of the common value in the law of sines in hyperbolic geometry

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

What is the geometrical meaning of the common value in the law of sines, $\frac{\sin A}{\sinh a} = \frac{\sin B}{\sinh b} = \frac{\sin C}{\sinh c}$ in hyperbolic geometry? I know the meaning of this value only in Euclidean and spherical geometry.

EDIT, Will Jagy. The OP is looking for some fourth fairly natural real number that can be calculated from a triangle, that gives the same answer as the common value in the Law of Sines. The original question is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69345/the-law-of-sines-in-hyperbolic-geometry

Comment: What is the meaning in spherical geometry?

Comment: this is the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69345/the-law-of-sines-in-hyperbolic-geometry  
where I suggested that there was no easy interpretation for the common value in the Law of Sines. Evidently in spherical geometry there is some ratio of volumes associated with the specific triangle.

Comment: Yes, I am searching for some help even here, maybe there is someone here who knows the answer. Sorry for the duplicate question, I can erase it if it creates problems.

Comment: Anything is possible. You should give details on your favorite interpretation in the spherical case, evidently you see this as a ratio of volumes. People need to see that. And do **not** call something a constant when it depends on the triangle chosen. 

Comment: @Will: there is an answer, and the quantity does not depend on the SIDE chosen, so it is invariant under A group of transformations.

Answer (score 3):

There is a meaning, though whether it is geometric is up to you to decide. You can see it in:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedLawofSines.html
which is fairly incomprehensible without
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicPolarSine.html

To see how you might derive such a thing, see this:
http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211261

Comment: Thanks, Igor. If you look at the MSE original question, it was a mess, in particular it completely misled me.

Comment: @Will: I am confused enough, I will take your word for it :)

Comment: Sounds good. It seems likely that the OP wants a ratio of two volumes in $\mathbf H^3,$ which seems to me a pretty good reason for expecting nothing easy. 

Comment: I am not sure why (s)he would, since in the Euclidean case the common value is is the circum-diameter...

Comment: Quoting: In spherical geometry it is the ratio of two volumes related to the triangle – Apotema (zar) 2 days ago

Comment: I think the OP is confused then...